# How to set the selected value of a (ajax) combobox with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, combobox, set

I have a gridview with row selection which should set the page's elements value by the selected id... When I press the row, I want my (ajax-editable)combobox to change its value(index) by the data turning from async page. I tried almost everything... Please need urgent help... :(

```
function VeriYaz(id) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "VeriAl.aspx",
            data: "id=" + id,
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                var urunler = data.split('|');
                document.getElementById('<%= cmbkategori.ClientID %>').value = stripHTML1(urunler[0]);}
        });
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `val([value])` function to set the selected value with jQuery:

```
$("#<%=DropDownList1.ClientID%>").val("1");
```

**EDIT**

If you want to set the selected value based on the data returning from your AJAX call, you should be able to do this:

```
$("#<%=DropDownList1.ClientID%>").val(stripHTML1(urunler[0]));
```

To set the selected item by the text, you can do this:

```
$("#<%=DropDownList1.ClientID%> option:contains(" + stripHTML1(urunler[0]) + ")").attr("selected", "selected");
```

**EDIT**

It sounds like you're using the AJAX Toolkit ComboBox, in which case you can try something like this:

```
$find("<%=ComboBox1.ClientID%>").get_textBoxControl().value = stripHTML1(urunler[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks James for your quick response, you r great man! :) But actually, I need it to change its value(index) by the data turning from async page : stripHTML1(urunler[0])

Comment: Just adap my example and set `stripHTML1(urunler[0])` to the value. I updated my example for you anyway though.

Comment: Thanks James but that gives an error: Object doesnt support this feature or method...

Comment: By the way is there a way to reach that combobox's textbox or text??

Comment: You want to set the text instead?

Comment: Yes ajax combobox has a textbox for edit as you know, maybe there is a work around to reach its textbox???

Comment: Updated my answer again. One of these has to be what you're looking for.

Comment: I'm confused. Are you using an auto-complete extender or something?

Comment: James, it doesnt have an option or smething it is an ajax combobox not a dropdown or select

Comment: Can you post the markup so I know what kind of control you're talking about?

Comment: <asp:ComboBox ID="cmbkategori" Width="100px" runat="server"></asp:ComboBox> (from ajax control toolkit) This is what you want or?

Comment: Okay, I think I understand what you need to do now. You should specfy Ajax Toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax ComboBox having the Hidden value..

You can do **only validation** from that hidden parameter..

```
$('#<%= id-of-combobox.ClientID%>_HiddenField').val();
```